Referencing a word in header with a command using Beamer
In Beamer, I want to reference a word of my first slide on subsequent slides using some command. How can I do this? The code is the following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    }{}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{I want \textit{word} here generated by ``I want \textit{some command} here''}

\begin{document}

\begin{withoutheadline}
\begin{frame}
This is a \textit{word}.
\end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}

\begin{frame}
My first slide...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
My second slide...
\end{frame}
\end{document}


I really do not understand what you want to achieve... If you simply want to define something once and reuse it, you can use \newcommand: \newcommand{\mytext}{hello} and then \mytext will produce hello.

I want something like: in first slide: This is a WORD\somecommand.  including in the preamble \setbeamertemplate{headline}{I want \somecommand here} in order to generate the following output: ''I want WORD here'' in headlines of subsequent slides.

@nplatis Would you like to post an answer? If I understand their comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722855/changing-color-of-title-in-theorem-environment-beamer#comment1798386_722856 correctly, then your idea to define a new command solved the problem.

If you want to define something once and reuse it, the simplest thing to do is by using \newcommand. For example, \newcommand{\mytext}{hello} will let you use \mytext to get hello.
