Changing color of title in theorem environment (Beamer)
How can I change the color of the title of example from green (default) to red? Here it is my code:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\example}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{example}
My first example...
\end{example}

\begin{example}
My second example...
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


The example block uses the block title example beamer colour for its title:
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\example}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
  \setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=red}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{example}
My first example...
\end{example}

\begin{example}
My second example...
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Many thanks. Please, just take a look on my other post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722848/referencing-a-word-in-header-with-a-command-using-beamer. Do you have any hint for this?

I had a look at your other question, but not really sure what you are asking there.

I want something like: write in the first slide: This is a WORD\somecommand (\somecommand will be a command similar to \ref{WORD} which allow to use the word WORD later). Now, I have to declare something in the preamble like \setbeamertemplate{headline}{I want \insertsomecommand here} which will generate the following output: ''I want WORD here'' in headlines of subsequent slides. I don't know what \insertsomecommand should be, neither \somecommand.

@CarlAnderson define a new command and use it in both places?

Yes, it works. Thanks
